# datepicker onSelect have selected day

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to get current element (the `td`) when in `onSelect` method?

If it's unclear, I want to add a specific class (for example `.active`) to the parent `td` of the current selected day (which has `ui-state-active` class).

Comment: And what's your HTML?

Comment: @j08691: nothing, because in `onSelect` I don't have it.

Comment: @TomWalters: my html? what do you mean? which I want, is something like that: `<td data-year="2015" data-month="10" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay" class="active"><a href="#" class="ui-state-default ui-state-active">8</a></td>`

Comment: Couldn't you just use the `ui-datepicker-current-day` class that jQuery adds to the day you select?

Comment: @j08691: it's for the `a` tag, I want something for the parent `td`.

Comment: No, the `ui-datepicker-current-day` is added to the `<td>` element, not the `<a>`. The `<a>` gets `ui-state-active`.

Comment: @j08691: Yeah, you're right. Please post this as an answer so I'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will actually make this easy for you by adding the `ui-datepicker-current-day` class to the table cell that you select. No extra code needed.

E.g.

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2015">
    <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">20</a>
</td>
```